# ingress controller with static ip address in a non cloud k8s cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller

I have a 5 node (vmware VMs) kubernetes cluster (running ubuntu). I installed nginx controller in the cluster exposed with LoadBalancer type. Now I want to make the nginx controller use a static IP as External IP that is available on one of the nodes (IP assigned to the secondary network interface attached to VM node). Is this implementation possible ?

Comment: better try it out, look into "hostNetwork" to disable pod network isolation and expose stuff directly on nodes -- though I'm not certain how that would behave with 2 NIC. Assuming it may not: a more traditional approach would involve something like "Multus"

Comment: I would give a look also at MetalLB https://metallb.universe.tf/ if you can lease this static external IP to the Kubernetes nodes.

Comment: How did you setup your Kubernetes cluster (kubeadm, kubespray etc.)? How exactly network look like on your VMs? Did you try already some solutions?

Comment: @Mikolaj S. This is kubeadm. All the vmware vms are in the same subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deployed ingress controller exposed as a NodePort service since could not find a way to use an additional network interface on master node as external IP for LoadBalancer service.